# blank BIOS screen before grub

Tags: boot, grub2

The update to Ubuntu 14.04 broke grub2 somehow and now my dual boot with Windows does not work.  Windows will not boot.  I have run boot-repair 4 or 5 times and still to no avail.  Along with the update to 14.04, the BIOS (HP Welcome) screen no longer appears before grub.  The monitor stays blank until grub appears. I have a HP Pavilion desktop from 2012. The only thing I can get to work is F2 brings up the diagnostics.  No other F keys bring up visible menus, though I think they bring up the menus and I just can't see them.

I have come to the conclusion that I need to reinstall 13.10 from live USB that I have, however, I can't boot from USB because I can't see any menus in order to access it.

Also, upon the last boot-repair, I obviously broke something in grub because the computer now boots to grub-repair.  I just want to boot the live USB and repair everything, but I need to find the BIOS screen again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured I would try a different monitor hooked up to the HP desktop via DVI cable instead of the Sigma Television hooked up by HDMI.  The BIOS bootup screen was back when I booted on the old monitor and I was able to reinstall Ubuntu 13.10 and have a fully functional dual-boot system again after boot-repair and Windows boot repair.